# color whole row instead of single cell

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework

Ive been trying to change the background color of a row in the Compact Framework DataGrid and have found little success since the DataGrid on .NET CF is limited compared to its Windows Forms counterpart. My only bit of success in achieving my goal is I have now been able to change the background color of a **single cell** depending on its values. I couldnt manipulate the code I got from Googling since I am not that good in C#. However, this is the code that I have:

```
namespace GridColor
{
    public delegate void CheckCellEventHandler(object sender, DataGridEnableEventArgs e);

    public class DataGridEnableEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int _column;
        private int _row;
        private bool _meetsCriteria;

        public DataGridEnableEventArgs(int row, int col, bool val)
        {
            _row = row;
            _column = col;
            _meetsCriteria = val;
        }

        public int Column
        {
            get { return _column; }
            set { _column = value; }
        }

        public int Row
        {
            get { return _row; }
            set { _row = value; }
        }

        public bool MeetsCriteria
        {
            get { return _meetsCriteria; }
            set { _meetsCriteria = value; }
        }

    }

    public partial class ColumnStyle : DataGridTextBoxColumn
    {
        //public event CheckCellEventHandler CheckCellEquals;
        public event CheckCellEventHandler CheckCellContains;

        private int _col;

        public ColumnStyle(int column)
        {
            _col = column;
        }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle Bounds, CurrencyManager Source, int RowNum, Brush BackBrush, Brush ForeBrush, bool AlignToRight)
        {
            bool enabled = true;

            if (CheckCellContains != null)
            {
                DataGridEnableEventArgs e = new DataGridEnableEventArgs(RowNum, _col, enabled);
                CheckCellContains(this, e);
                if (e.MeetsCriteria)
                    //g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), Bounds.Y + 1, Bounds.Width - 2, Bounds.Height - 2);
                    BackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.PaleGreen);
            }

            base.Paint(g, Bounds, Source, RowNum, BackBrush, ForeBrush, AlignToRight);

        }
    }

}
```

Now for my form, I have this:

```
namespace GridColor
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            DataSet ds;
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            private List<string> compareValues = new List<string>();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                try
                {
                    addGridStyle(ref dataGrid1);
                    compareValues.Add("OK");
                    compareValues.Add("Filling");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }

            private void addGridStyle(ref DataGrid dg)
            {
                DataGridTableStyle dtStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
                dtStyle.MappingName = "Test";

                string connString = "Data Source=192.168.2.16,1433;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=ABC12abc;";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Test";
                ds = new DataSet();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds, "Test");

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Test"].Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    ColumnStyle myStyle = new ColumnStyle(i);
                    myStyle.MappingName = ds.Tables["Test"].Columns[i].ToString();
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        if (ds.Tables["Test"].Columns[i].DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
                            myStyle.CheckCellContains += new CheckCellEventHandler(myStyle_CheckCellContains);
                    }
                    dtStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(myStyle);
                }

                dg.TableStyles.Add(dtStyle);
            }

            public void myStyle_CheckCellContains(object sender, DataGridEnableEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (compareValues.Contains((string)dataGrid1[e.Row, e.Column]))
                        e.MeetsCriteria = true;
                    else
                        e.MeetsCriteria = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    e.MeetsCriteria = false;
                }
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Test"];
            }
        }
    }
```

**In what part of my code should I change so that If a cell meets the criteria, its whole row will be colored instead of only it's own cell?**

Comment: I've done this exact thing, I believe, but unfortunately I do not have access to the code right now. Maybe tonight I can find it for you.

Comment: I did something similar, I believe I had a custom event that was fired, I handled the event, and then using the args filled in the correct brush. It might be that each column has to be your custom type and just fire a lot of events. Again.. I'll see if I can find it

Comment: Thanks. I was actually thinking about determining the value of cell and if it meets the criteria I guess Ill fire up something to color the cell for each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I went back and found my code from years ago where I did this on the desktop, before the more advanced DataGridView came out, etc.

First of all there is this tutorial from Microsoft [Customizing the Windows Forms DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996485.aspx), which explains how to highlight an entire row.

I looked at my code and I had to add a custom column style for **each** column, fire an event to the main form which I handled, and then determined the proper color for that record. Then, I set the args.Color property and the DataGridColumn would draw the correct color. **So yes, you have to actually have each column be your custom formatable class, then your application logic can handle the event, get the record data and determine the color**

** Update: here's a simple example **

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    FormattableTextBoxColumn firstNameColumn = new FormattableTextBoxColumn();
    FormattableTextBoxColumn lastNameColumn = new FormattableTextBoxColumn();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // add first name col
        firstNameColumn.MappingName = "FirstName";
        dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(firstNameColumn);
        firstNameColumn.SetCellFormat += new FormatCellEventHandler(ColumnSetCellFormat);

        // add last name col
        lastNameColumn.MappingName = "LastName";
        lastNameColumn.SetCellFormat += new FormatCellEventHandler(ColumnSetCellFormat);
        dataGridTableStyle1.GridColumnStyles.Add(lastNameColumn);

        // This just sets up a dummy data source, since I don't have a database in this example
        List<PersonTest> peopleList = new List<PersonTest>();
        peopleList.Add(new PersonTest
        {
            FirstName = "Alan",
            LastName = "QQQQQ",
            HighlightPerson = true
        });
        peopleList.Add(new PersonTest
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Smith",
            HighlightPerson = false
        });
        BindingSource peopleDataSource = new BindingSource();
        peopleDataSource.DataSource = peopleList;
        dataGridTableStyle1.MappingName = peopleDataSource.GetListName(null);
        dataGrid1.DataSource = peopleDataSource;
    }

    // I'll cache this brush in the form, just make sure to dispose it (see designer.cs disposing)
    SolidBrush highlightBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);

    // here is the event you can handle to determine the color of your row!
    private void ColumnSetCellFormat(object sender, DataGridFormatCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Source.List[e.Row] as PersonTest).HighlightPerson)
            e.BackBrush = highlightBrush;
    }

    // example test class
    public class PersonTest
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public bool HighlightPerson { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the custom data grid column

```
public class FormattableTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextBoxColumn
{
    public event FormatCellEventHandler SetCellFormat;

    protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)
    {
        DataGridFormatCellEventArgs e = new DataGridFormatCellEventArgs(rowNum, source);
        e.ForeBrush = foreBrush;
        e.BackBrush = backBrush;
        OnSetCellFormat(e);
        base.Paint(g, bounds, source, rowNum, e.BackBrush, e.ForeBrush, alignToRight);
    }

    private void OnSetCellFormat(DataGridFormatCellEventArgs e)
    {
        FormatCellEventHandler handler = SetCellFormat;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

You'll also need this DataGridCellEventArgs.cs

```
public delegate void FormatCellEventHandler(object sender, DataGridFormatCellEventArgs e);

public class DataGridFormatCellEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Row;
    public CurrencyManager Source;
    public Brush BackBrush;
    public Brush ForeBrush;

    public DataGridFormatCellEventArgs(int row, CurrencyManager manager)
    {
        this.Row = row;
        this.Source = manager;
    }
}
```

Here's an example project for you:

[DataGridTest.zip](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxrjI2SEpdk6NEhzelNWUkhDRTQ)

Comment: Hi. Could you provide a sample of you project for me to try. I'm finding it hard to understand your question.

Comment: @jeraldov Alright, sorry. I had to make some changes to make it work on the CompactFramework. I updated my code and provided a downloadable example project that I tested and it works. You may need to expand it to make it better, but it should show proof of concept. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with CF, but I thought I would throw this out there... If you can access the cell, wouldn't the row be it's `NamingContainer`?  If so you could drill up to the row and apply a style or add an attribute with a CSS class.

Comment: well, I can already access/identify the cell if it meets a criteria. my problem now is how do I color the whole row, instead of just the single cell.

Comment: Can't you cast the cells `NamingContainer` as a row and then run logic against that object?

Comment: Im not sure what NamingContainer you are talking about. Ive even checked the docs for .NET and NamingContainer is not included in .NET CF.

Comment: My fault. I didn't realize it was specific to the System.Web.UI namespace. There is still a control tree in the CF, right? There has to be some way to traverse it.