# Changing color of Selected row of DataGrid by touch

Tags: c#, compact-framework, smartphone

I am new in smart device application development. I got very few options in DataGrid of Smart Device. Can anyone suggest me the correct event and solution to change Background color of selected row in DataGrid.

Comment: What version of the compact framework are you using? By the [smartphone] tag, do you mean to say you are building your application using the Windows Mobile 6 SDK?

Comment: If you need more help I can be more specific and try to get you an example, just let me know

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question before for the DataGrid in the CompactFramework. Please see my answer in this question. [Color whole row instead of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908705/color-whole-row-instead-of-single-cell/12983422#12983422)

Hope this helps. There's even an example project that I provided for download at the end of my answer.

In my example, I handle the paint for a DataGridColumn you can use that event to check if you are the currently selected row and paint whatever color you like.

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)
    {
        DataGridFormatCellEventArgs e = new DataGridFormatCellEventArgs(rowNum, source);
        e.ForeBrush = foreBrush;
        e.BackBrush = backBrush;
        OnSetCellFormat(e);
        base.Paint(g, bounds, source, rowNum, e.BackBrush, e.ForeBrush, alignToRight);
    }
```

Right there on base.Paint you can pass in different brushes etc.